# How to calculate relative frequency from two lists

Tags: python-2.7, frequency-distribution

This is the outputs of my code:

```
List1=[('a',6),('b',7),('c',4)]
List2=[(('a','x'),2),(('a','y'),3),((b,z),2)]
```

What I am trying to figure out is probablity of occurence 'a' w.r.t 'x'? Which means I have to calculate

```
occurrence('a','x')/occurrence ('a')=2/6=0.333
```

How to calculate for all possible items? eg. `(b,7)` and `((b,z),2)` and all. But there is no need for cases like this- (c,4) and ((b,z),2) etc.

Comment: can you clarify how you obtained list1 and list2

Comment: By ngram and FreqDist()